# php did not send data by using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is a code with `DropDown` list which can update the database upon on change, it doesn't work for some reason. I realize that the value `$ gp_name` didn't send out, can someone help me to fix it?

```
<select name='status' id='status'>
<option value="<?php echo $status ?>"><?php echo $status ?></option>
<option value="Inquiry">Inquiry</option>

</select>
<input type="hidden" name="gp_name" id="gp_name" value="<?php echo $gp_name;?>" />
<div id="autosavenotify"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var statusVal = $(this).val();
  var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
  alert(statusVal,gp_name);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    data: {
      statusType: statusVal,
      gp_name: gp_name
    },
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
    }
  })
});
});
</script>
```

save.php

```
<?php
require_once("connMysql.php");
$gp_name=$_POST['gp_name'];
$st=$_POST['statusType'];
$qry ="UPDATE lotus_gp SET status='".$st."' where gp_name='".$gp_name."'";
$done = mysql_query($qry);
if($done)
{
echo $gp_name;
echo $st;
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `$gp_name` before defining it?  That would be a problem of course...

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="gp_name" id="gp_name" value="<?php echo $gp_name;?>" /` ...where is it getting $gp_name from in that line? Is there more script above that which you didn't include? And have you checked the generated HTML source to see if a value is actually printed inside the hidden field, or not? It's unclear. Also, ensure PHP error/warning reporting is switched on, then you'll see notifications about undefined variables etc.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the website, I have fixed the problem now, forgot to give value to gp_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if the data is getting from your front-end sides on your PHP page.

```
if(isset($_POST['gp_name']) && isset($_POST['statusType'])){
  $gpname = $_POST['gp_name']; // echo it to ensure
  $satype = $_POST['statusType']; // echo it to ensure
}
```

If the data is not printed then you might have an issue with inputs.